# Add conference time in EST/PST on admin site and display conferences on site accordingly

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I have a requirement to let admin users add a conference through an admin web site. Admin user will enter the conference name, desc and time of the conference, along with the timezone (only for US - EST/CST/PST). This then is displayed on the public website for customers. I need to be able to display the list of conferences with their correct times.

I'm thinking of storing the datetime (1/1/2012 8:00 AM and timezone (EST=0) in the database for the conference table.

Is there another way to achieve this?

Comment: The admin user needs to enter the conference. There is no existing list. Admin user could be in NY entering a conference information for California.

Comment: let me rephrase my question.. what type of interface / GUI / Web or web service are they using to enter the data..its this a shared Excel or web app or Sharepoint.. more info would have been better from the start...

Comment: Admin is a web site too. I updated the question. Admin site and public facing site both talk to the same database.

Answer (score 0):

Use UTC in SqlServer.  Then capture the time of the user on the website (preference table or whatever) then when you display the meeting request, take the UTC time and convert it to local time.

This will be better than storing the timezone the meeting was created in, because you'll have to convert timezones (e.g. EST to MDT).

Another concern is that if you store timezone, you'll have to know whether it's daylight savings time (EST or EDT) and then convert to either CST or CDT etc.  If you store as UTC and then use that on your server, with Kind = UTC on the datetime object, .NET can handle if there needs to be conversion based on DST or timezone etc.

Comment: well, remember that an admin user has to enter the information about this conference. He will have to specifically say this is a conference in California. I can't make him choose a UTC as he wont know what it is.

Comment: If they add it why couldn't the code be implemented based on where they are that  should work.. unless they have some other way of adding in information / time..?

Comment: Yeah, but the admin will be entering the data in a time zone, on a page that goes through the server.  The server can convert to UTC (it's built in to the .NET framework) before it's saved in the DB.

Comment: right, but admin could be in east coast entering a conference information for west coast. i cannot automatically assume the timezone of the server.

Comment: No, you let the admin say "This is happening at 5pm PDT" but when the user comes in to view it, then you can convert to their time from UTC.

Comment: I think i'll just use the new datetimeoffset field in sql 2008. This way I can display PST/EST on the user site as well.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to capture the local users time zone from the moment they enter the data use code like this.

```
string CurrentTimeZoneAbbreviation = System.TimeZoneInfo.Local.Abbreviation();
```

Comment: The admin user entering the conference information could be in east coast entering a new conference for west coast.

Comment: Ok I got cha Alex.. I didn't see the west coast part.. looks like Validations would have to be implented on the existing as well to make sure that they enter a TimeZone to